# How to Fetch all role names and ids created by developer or user( not system created)

Tags: soql, query, roles

When i am querying the "Select id,name from UserRole" then all roles are getting fetch with the  system roles  and created by user/admin/developer..
Is there any way to fetch the roles created by user/dev/admin.Please Suggest

Answer (score 1):

An imperfect but probably workable solution:

If you want to see who is changing metadata such as Roles, go to `Setup | View Setup Audit Trail`

You can go back 6 months in time. You'll get the SFDC username that, if you really care, can be cross-referenced to the User SObjects and admin versus user vs dev breakouts can be ascertained.  The normal use case for this issue is "who made some system change?" and is typically a one-off.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There is no field on the object UserRole that specifies who created the Role, so unfortunately, you cannot filter in the query on that field.

See https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_role.htm for a complete description of the available fields.